# How to integrate Jobs in Jenkins using Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Four Jobs- A,B,C,D

A- Build

B- Test

C- Sonar Analysis

D- Deploy

My scenario-

1- I need to create a Pipeline
A->B->C

2- I Need to create a other Pipeline
A->B->D

My issue is--

1- If I select "Trigger Parameterized builds on other projects " and add Job B under Job A, I can't use Job A for my second scenario.

How should I use Job A for both the pipelines without effecting.

Comment: Are you sure you are using [jenkins pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) ? It doesn't seems so, as you describe selecting "Trigger Parameterized builds on other projects".

Comment: @Pom12   Yes.. i am using Jenkins pipeline. I am using "Trigger Parameterized builds on other projects" as well.

Comment: I'm asking the question because "Trigger parameterized builds on other project" option is **only** available for **freestyle jobs**, not **pipelines jobs**. Are you using pipelines **scripts** ? If so, can you describe which job is a freestyle job and which one is a pipeline ? Also, what is the trigger condition for job A ? Will it be triggered manually, from Git, ... ?

Comment: None of the jobs are Pipeline. All the jobs are Freestyle.Job A will fetch code from Git Hub repository and build sol and Proj file in Release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to create two pipelines. In the pipelines, you can define which jobs to build using stages.

For your requirement, you need to create two pipelines and define stages according to your needs. `Trigger Parameterized builds on other projects` is not a suitable option for you.

```
stage('Build A') {
build job: 'A' , parameters: <Give_your_own_parameters>
}

stage('Build B') {
build job: 'B' , parameters: <Give_your_own_parameters>
}
stage('Build C') {
build job: 'C' , parameters: <Give_your_own_parameters>
}
```

You can also get the syntax from `Pipeline Syntax` in the `Pipeline` Section of the pipeline you are building.

Comment: Do you have any solution for the same

Comment: Like mentionned in the comments below, Bhave is not using pipelines in the Jenkins meaning but is just using multiple **freestyle jobs** that are chained together, forming a workflow or a pipeline... of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can ease the process by creating a duplicate project of A, and B. Project can easily be duplicated during **New Item> Copy details from Project A**.

Comment: Do we have any alternate solution other than duplication the jobs

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy feasible for a simple reason : you are not using Jenkins jobs the way they were meant to be used.

The concept of a job in Jenkins is that **a job is a sequence of actions**. A job does not have a single responsibility such as just building, just testing or just deploying. In your case, you should have 3 "actions" in a job, and 3 "actions" in another job.

### The freestyle job approach

The common approach would be something like :

**Build job**

1. Action 1 : build
2. Action 2 : test
3. Action 3 : run Sonar analysis

**Deploy job**

1. Action 1 : build
2. Action 2 : test
3. Action 3 : deploy

Unless I'm missing something here, you don't want to separate these 3/4 actions in 4 separate jobs, as this would be **highly inneficient**. For example, test phase and Sonar analysis should probably be run just after a code build has been made, so you want to share the same workspace to be able to test your built code.

### The pipeline approach

Another - preferred - approach would be to use actual [Jenkins pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/), i.e. Groovy scripts that will allow you to define your steps as functions and then reuse them in both your "Build job" and "Deploy job".

As an example, you could have a functions.groovy containing your build/test functions :

**functions.groovy**

```
def build() {
  // Build code here...
}

def test() {
  // Test code here...
}
```

**build-job.groovy**

```
node {
   def functions = load 'functions.groovy'

   stage('Build') {
       functions.build()
   }
   stage('Test') {
       functions.test()
   }
   stage('Sonar Analysis') {
       // Sonar analysis code...
   }
}
```

**deploy-job.groovy**

```
node {
   def functions = load 'functions.groovy'

   stage('Build') {
       functions.build()
   }
   stage('Test') {
       functions.test()
   }
   stage('Deploy') {
       // Deploy code...
   }
}
```